# Does git branch -D branch-name really deletes specified branch

Tags: git

Whenever I want to delete a branch I do this

```
git branch -D branch-name
```

I have read that this deletes the branch and as a result of this I didn't the same branch when I did

```
git branch
```

But I was amazed when I pressed tab few times after writing `git checkout`
I could see all my branches (deleted ones too) and I was able to checkout in those branches.

I am kind of confused now.

Comment: It really does. Are you maybe looking at remote branches?

Comment: @Ryan Yes you are correct I had no idea that git will search for remote branches. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete a branch it deleted your local branch. If you will check it out again you will have the branch checked out.

Whenever you checkout a branch git search to see if its exists locally. If it does not it searched the remotes for the given name and than check it out. The remotes branches are not deleted when you delete local branch so you can always check them out again.

[image]

Comment: A text transcript would be more helpful than a screenshot, especially since visitors using mobile devices have limited screen real estate.